# Identity column in view of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which has a Identity Column.

When I tried to create a view (with only this table), everything is still working fine, the ID property(which is used to mark auto increment number column) of Identity Column is still set to True

[When there is only 1 table in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPoB.png)

[Here is the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/johoq.png)

But when I tried to create a view by join the mentioned above table with another table, the Identity Column is automatically set to false.

[When I try to join 2 tables in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLnkB.png)

[Here is the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJnS0.png)

This problem occurs maybe only in SQL Server 2016 (I tried with SQL Server 2008, it's still working fine)

Did anyone encounter similar problems? How to keep true value of Identity Column in View? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean the identity column is set to false? What exactly is happening?

Comment: @Ben I have uploaded some photos, hope it's clear enough. As you can see the ID property of the identity column is set to false when I tried to join 2 table in a view

Comment: I think you'll find that just means you can't insert using the view with 2 joined tables. You get results when you read from it right?

Comment: @Ben actually, I'm not going to insert anything, but I need this ID property set to "True". Then I can link it with my access Database and do some other stuffs. But I'm stucked here right now. 
Before when I use SQL 2008, this worked fine, the column keeps ID property is "true" from the identity column of its source table. But after I tried to use SQL 2016, I encountered the problem.

Comment: Identity "True" just means that when new rows are inserted that column is treated an an Identity column (i.e., auto-generated identity value under normal circumstances). It's not a relational thing as such.

Comment: Please avoid having too much information in pictures or images. Also note, that whatever language is in those pictures, almost no one will understand it since Stack Overflow is an English language site.